# How do I run a function from a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run a function from a variable I've defined although it's not working.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function red () {
       alert("You chose the color red");
    }
    function blue () {
       alert("You chose the color blue");
    }

    $(window).resize(function() {

        var colorvalue = "blue" + "();";
        return colorvalue

    });

});
```

If someone could correct my faulty logic that would be helpful, thanks.

SOLVED! FULL SOLUTION HERE

```
function red () {
    alert("You chose the color red");
}
function blue () {
    alert("You chose the color blue");
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).resize(function() {

        var colorvalue = "blue";
        var callable = window[colourvalue];
        callable();

    });

});
```

Comment: try `return eval(colorvalue)`

Comment: that could work...although I heard eval is evil, is there an alternative?

Comment: :) I don't see anything wrong in using it for something this simple

Comment: @rps There are many better ways to do this that don't involve `eval()`. If there's another way to do something without `eval()`, then the `eval()` method is almost always going to be the less efficient, worse way to do it.

Comment: @Cuberto, yea if a better alternative comes along, why not... I don't like to use `eval()` either but the code required to _evaluate JS as string_, so I suggested it for something this simple.

Comment: @rps most cases of using `eval()` happen because the developer doesn't realize they can dynamically build identifiers with square brackets - `var obj = { method1: function() {}, method2: function() {} }; var whichMethod = 2; obj["method" + whichMethod]()`

Comment: @Cuberto hmmm user objects are good way to go about it.

Comment: @rps basically, if all of the code is yours, there should be no reason to store it in a string and run it with `eval`. Read this article - http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/ - it explains why most cases of using `eval` indicate bad code and the problems associated with it.

Comment: @Cuberto like that title said _eval() **isn’t evil**, just misunderstood_  and I didn't see any grave danger in this simple solution but I get your point it is better to not get used to using eval for tiny tweaks, I agree with you.

Comment: Looks like the non-eval solution in the comments didn't work. eval(); did work however so thanks. I'll check out the article you linked Cuberto as I feel as though I should know more about eval() and whether this is the best approach in this case.

Comment: @rpm The relevant part of that article is this: "The use of eval() is inappropriate here because it’s ***unnecessary*** not because it’s bad. You can easily rewrite this function as:" - Eval is ***slow*** and hard to debug. You can do what OP wants without eval.

Comment: @GSimon, :) I was actually going to ask you "did it _really_ work, the one you had marked as answer?"

Comment: @Cuberto, Waving white flag mate :), you should edit your answer with the one you had typed in your comments(user objects), it will be helpful to OP!

Comment: @rps I was a bit confused myself since it didn't seem to be a scope problem. When I realized the mistake I felt bad because I thought I had maybe confused a lot of the people who were trying to help by marking the solution as correct lol.

Comment: @GSimon, lol nothing like that, Glad you found the solution now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will work absolutely

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
    var callable = window["blue"];
callable();
});
```

Try it

Comment: This worked!!

However it was also a scope problem as others mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var red = function{ alert("You chose the color red"); };
var blue = function{ alert("You chose the color blue"); };
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).resize(function() {

        var colorvalue = window["blue"];
        return colorvalue();

    });

});
```

This way you can evaluate the target function to call without using `eval`.

Comment: I'll have a go at this and the solution posted above, I'll report back if things work out (could be few mins..)

Answer (score 1):

Put your function out of you Document ready function. like below

```
function red() {
    alert("You chose the color red");
}
function blue() {
    alert("You chose the color blue");
}

$(document).ready(function () {


    $(window).resize(function () {

        var colorvalue = "blue" + "();";
        return eval(colorvalue);

    });

});
```

if you want to use in document ready then use like onclick to particular id : exp: $( "#target" ).click();
[REF](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: This seemed to be the problem. Thanks

Comment: Correction, it didn't really pan out. In my rush to try out the solution I wrote: var colorvalue = blue instead of var colorvalue = "blue" so I was calling the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

you should try

```
return eval(colorvalue);
```

Comment: This is the solution I am using until I can find a non eval approach that may be a better solution than this.

Answer (score 1):

Set up an object with your functions as methods. (This avoids multiple globals.)

```
var colour = {
    red: function{ ... },
    blue: function{ ... }
}
```

Then call `colour[myOption]` where `myOption` is set to be "blue" or "red" somehow (probably by the user).

Comment: This is likely a more elegant option than the one I ended up using, I may use this approach instead later. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @GSimon Thanks. I almost put a comment under the answer you selected, but I decided it would be seen as churlish to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
var red = function(){
     // doSomething
}

var blue = function(){
    //doSomething
}
```

Comment: I had a go at this approach also although it seems to produce the same result. I found a solution in one of the comments though but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
var colorvalue = blue;
return colorvalue();
```

Though note that the [`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPInstall_API_Reference/Install_Object/Methods/alert) function doesn't return anything, and your functions aren't even returning anything, so right now your functions will return `undefined`. Perhaps you meant to define them like:

```
function blue () {
  var msg = "You chose the color blue";
  alert(msg);
  return msg;
}
```

Comment: I'll have a go at this and the solution posted below, I'll report back if things work out (could be few mins..)

Comment: I get this console error when trying this approach

Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function 

I did a console.log to verify that I had the correct value as well.

Comment: Are you sure you copied my code exactly? It sounds like you called the `blue` function, and then called the result of the first call.

Comment: My script is a bit more involved than the example I provided so I didn't copy the function provided. Sorry for any confusion, I probably should have left out the alert function in the example as I am not using alerts